# Add/remove indicies in AngularJS model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

AngularJS ubern00b here. Here's an angular module that I built:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('RentalAppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.update = function(rentalApp) {
      console.log('updating scope');
      $scope.master = angular.copy(rentalApp);
    }

    $scope.reset = function() {
      console.log('resetting scope');
      $scope.master = angular.copy($scope.master);
    }

    $scope.reset();

    $scope.rentalApp = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
      history: {
        "0": {
          address: '',
          city: '',
          state: 'IN',
          zip: '',
        },
        "1": {
          address: '',
          city: '',
          state: 'IN',
          zip: '',
        },
        "2": {
          address: '',
          city: '',
          state: 'IN',
          zip: '',
        }
      }
    }
}]);
```

My `rentalApp` has a radio input that dictates the number of `history` objects that will be submitted to the API. I love the data binding features of Angular, and ideally I'd like the value of the radio button input to determine the size of the history object.

In PHP I would use something like `array_push` or `array_pop` to add or remove the necessary `history` objects from the `rentalApp` model.

What is the `Angular` way to do this?

Comment: why don't you design the `history` object as an array

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4Nk5K/1/ ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny make than an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" value="1" ng-model="historyCount" />
    <input type="radio" value="2" ng-model="historyCount" />
    <input type="radio" value="3" ng-model="historyCount" />
    <input type="radio" value="4" ng-model="historyCount" />
</div>
<div ng-repeat="history in rentalApp.history">
    <input ng-model="history.address" />
</div>
```

then

```
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function () {

});

app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.update = function (rentalApp) {
        console.log('updating scope');
        $scope.master = angular.copy(rentalApp);
    };

    $scope.reset = function () {
        console.log('resetting scope');
        $scope.master = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };

    $scope.reset();

    $scope.rentalApp = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        history: [{
            address: '',
            city: '',
            state: 'IN',
            zip: ''
        }, {
            address: '',
            city: '',
            state: 'IN',
            zip: ''
        }, {
            address: '',
            city: '',
            state: 'IN',
            zip: ''
        }]
    };

    $scope.historyCount = $scope.rentalApp.history.length;
    $scope.$watch('historyCount', function (value) {
        if (value < $scope.rentalApp.history.length) {
            $scope.rentalApp.history.splice(value);
        } else if (value > $scope.rentalApp.history.length) {
            while (value != $scope.rentalApp.history.length) {
                $scope.rentalApp.history.push({
                    address: '',
                    city: '',
                    state: 'IN',
                    zip: ''
                })
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4Nk5K/)